# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable, android-bundle

I have an `arraylist` that i want to send from 1 activity to another, I am using serializable but end up getting following error message.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException
>   writing serializable object (name = com.app...)

*I have also reviewed some question regarding this on `SO`, most of them saying that all classes defined inside your `Serialized` class should also implement `Serializable`, but here `Path`, 'RectF', `Matrix`, are not my classes, they are android classes, and i can't implement `Serializable`  in these classes.*

This is how i am sending array list from 1 activity to another.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("PATH_LIST", pathsList);
        bundle.putString("FILE_NAME", fileName);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this is my class.

```
public class TData implements Serializable {

    Matrix originalMatrix;
    public Path path;
    PointF position;



    private TData attachedPathData;
    public void setAttachedPathData(TData pathData){
        attachedPathData = pathData;
    }
    public TData getAttachedPathData(){
        return attachedPathData;
    }


    public TData(){

    }


    public TData(Path path, PointF position, String id, String fillColor, String strokeColor){
        this.path = path;
        this.position = position;
        this.id = id;

        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    }

    public void Scale(float scaleX, float scaleY){
        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        RectF rectF = new RectF();
        path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
        scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX,scaleY);
        path.transform(scaleMatrix);


        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        path.computeBounds(rf, true);

        Region r = new Region();

    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please post the entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here Path, 'RectF', Matrix, are not my classes, they are android classes, and i can't implement Serializable in these classes..

Then do not have fields for them in `Serializable` classes.

Either:

- Do not have separate activities here, but do something else instead (e.g., one activity and two fragments) that avoids the need for the `Intent`, or
- Do not pass this data between the activities, but instead use a different application architecture (e.g., the data is not held by either activity, but instead is held by a repository that both activities can talk to), or
- Create some data structure that you can make `Parceable` or `Serializable`, from which you can rebuild your model objects with their desired classes, and pass that `Parcelable`/`Serializable` data structure in the `Intent` instead of `TData`